# Custom View Controllers and Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode-storyboard

I'm working on an OS X app and exploring the use of storyboards. My app has a three pane layout - a vertical SplitView with a horizontal SplitView embedded in the right-hand vertical split item.

I'd like to have custom (subclassed) view controllers for each of the split view items' views (and for other embedded views). It seems the only way to accomplish this is to create a new view controller scene for each view controller I want - I see no way to create a custom view controller class for a non-top level view in an existing scene.

That's fine, but it seems once I split out each view controller into its own scene, there's no way to set autolayout constraints on top-level scene views - the autolayout controls are disabled in the IB UI. There doesn't seem to be a way to use autolayout between scenes.

Am I missing something? I'd like to have the options to have custom view controllers and autolayout controls for all views in my app. Do I need to resort to code to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use for "Container Views".

Drag a "Container View" into each of your panes and you'll see another child UIViewController appear in the storyboard. You can then use those new UIViewControllers as usual, whilst also setting the constraints on the parent "Container View".

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I hadn't noticed earlier when I drag in a container view, that a controller gets added.

Comment: @Jamesford - really glad to hear that it helped. Please mark it as the answer when you get a chance :-)